# how to create a Web-Service in Node-JS

Tags: node.js, express

**HI friends** ... this might be a silly question but its hard for a beginner like me
.
I am trying to lean about webservices
I have created a sample program in express that outputs a JSON

```
var http=require('http');
var express=require('express');


var app=express();


app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 5000);
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});


app.get("/",function(req,res){

    res.json({Message:"HELLO_WORLD"});
});



http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function(){
    console.log("Server is running at port:" + app.get('port'));
});
```

- I am able to execute this on my aws server when i run on it
- how to access it from another desktop(ex:my home-PC)

*when i give `localhost:5000` it dosen't work. According to my knowledge the solution is `WEBSERVICES` .*

---

how to create it .... what additional lines of code i need to add for this existing code. or if i need to create any other configuration file .... how to do it?
.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What is your error message, is it EADDINUSE? it's mean another version of your code still running and your port now in use, or some other application is using the port 5000. You should turn off your code or change the port

Comment: Btw, you can check your local ip address, so other computer can access your service via that ip: http://your_ip:your_port

Comment: Hey thanks ... error cleared ..... what url should i need to give from local PC ? .... is it like http://myamazonserverip:5000

Comment: Oh!I guess you are running it on server right? If you run your service on a server, just use its ip, i'm not sure about port because your application will first read the enviroment parameter for port, the log message will tell you which port will be used, it usually port 80, you can try it first. If you run it on your pc, so use your local ip.

Answer (score 0):

Just use app.listen not http.createServer

```
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send(200);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the i/p .... but i get an error when i use the above code as :: events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:884:11)

Comment: Adding to above comment .... without creating server how r u able to listen with above code snippet ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine. Make sure you have express installed in the `node_modules` directory on the pc from which you are trying to execute the code.

Comment: HI Akshant ..... I have express module installed ... im running it on AWS(amazon server) ...... then i am trying to call it from my desktop PC with url in my browser .... here its not working